# nodejs: send new file contents to a server everytime line gets added to file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am an absolute nodejs beginner and facing problem in implementing even simple stuff. I want to implement following situation

1. I have 2 machines (m1, m2) who are writing logs to a file (~/Desktop/logs).
2. Every time a new line gets added to my logs file, I want to send those new lines to a central machine (mCentral).

Please note that it is continue ongoing process. My logs file are not complete but they are getting populated continuously.

Any help/hint will be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: read more about [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve your problem using socket.io

> Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication.

In your case, you have 2 servers, each one writes to log file, so after the function that writes, you have to emit an event that we logged a message and then we will catch this event in the client machine "mcentral". you didn't post your source code, but after including socket io, it will be somehow like that :

**Machines m1 and m2**

```
var io= require("socket.io").listen(http); 
// http is your HTTP server created with require("http")
// your function writes in log file a variable called line
// We will emit an event to mcentral that we logged line
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {              
    socket.broadcast.emit('logging', {message: line}); // we emit an event
}); 
});
// our server is listening on port 3000 (example)
http.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("Listening on 3000");
});
```

**Machine mcentral**
In a simple web page, i will listen an event called logging that we created in machines m1 and m2, when catching this event, we will show the line added in a html section (my example)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> List </title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="zone_msg">
    </section>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
         var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
         socket.on('logging', function(data) {
              $('#zone_msg').prepend('<p> </strong> ' + data.message + '</p>');             
        })     
    </script>
</body>
```

Socket.io is real time and help you resolve such problems, If my example is not very clear, you can check other ressources like [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/Readme.md) and [here](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I think that I could not convey my requirement clearly.
My M1 and M2 are NOT writing to log files. Some other process is writing to those files. M1 and M2 are trying to send those logs (on new arrival) to central machine.

Comment: As i told you, you didn't post you source code..anyway, you can still use my example replacing the writing function with a function that check the new line added to the log file, then emit this line in a logging event and catch it on the central machine, i think this a good solution for your problem

Comment: Hi oussama, Thanks for your recommendations. I solved the issue using rsyslog.